# Notify a page when a new item has been posted

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am developing a web application using AJAX and I wanted to know if it possible to notify a page which contains a list of items when a new one has been successfully added from another page.

```
$(function(){
var $name = $("#nameTxtB");
var $order = $("#orderTxtB");
var $price = $("#priceTxtB");

$("#addButton").on('click', function(){
var $try1 = $price.val();
var $parse = parseInt($try1);

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'http://localhost:51834/CoffeeService.svc/addorder/',
headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
data: JSON.stringify({
Name: $name.val(),
Order: $order.val(),
Price: $parse,
}),

  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(){
  alert("Order was sucessfully created!");
  setTimeout(function() {
  location.reload();
}, 500);
},
   error: function(){
   alert("Something went wrong!");
     }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: It would probably get heavy, but you'd have to write a timeout function that runs every `x` amount of time to check if something has been posted, then if it has, pull it with ajax and show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `"setinterval(function(){},interval)"` to continously check the length of your list item, if it gets updated, there is successful addition of item. 
But there will be performance issues to continously watching list item using setInterval. Its better to run a seperate thread using **HTML 5 Web Worker** and do the **setinterval** in web worker, this can be alternate way.
**For web worker** : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: The HTML 5 Web Worker seems very handy when it comes to these things :D But I would need some time to understand how to use it with AJAX! Thank you for the tip, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible... There are a number of solutions with varying Pros/Cons.

Basic approach is Polling - I.E. do an ajax call every x seconds to check for new items.

For more complex approach look into SignalR framework which uses web sockets etc. to send updates back. This will be much better in terms of performance as you don't make unnecessary calls when there are no new items, but is a bit more complicated to implement...